# Making a twitter mono client

Tags: c#, twitter, mono

Hey everyone! i am making a small twitter client using mono i just whant to know if there good librarys i could use. Currently i am using twitterizer http://www.twitterizer.net but mono isn't officialy supported.

I am new in this so any comments and links are welcome.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't use it, though - you just might have to help them debug the library if you run into problems. There are twitter libraries out there that do test on mono, e.g. http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/ but I don't know it well enough to recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't officially support using Mono with Twitterizer, only because I've barely ever used Mono and so I couldn't be relied on for support.

There have been a few Mono projects to successfully implement Twitterizer, most notably Smuxi (http://www.smuxi.org/main/). Although they are a few revisions behind, their source code would be good start if you're looking to modify Twitterizer for use with Mono.

Comment: Also, if you do end up using Twitterizer with Mono, please let me know what modifications (if any) you needed to make. I would be willing to include these changes in the next revision to allow for support out-of-the-box.